# Cannot get service worker to register on Angular app serving over HTTP

Tags: angular, google-chrome, firefox

This is in either Chrome (v. 104) or Firefox (103).

I have followed the instructions for enabling service workers in each case. Service workers from external https sites register fine; from an http site, even localhost, specifying the port, the worker is simply ignored.

For either browser, what are the exact settings that must be used?